# Как перекрасить здания на Яндекс-Карте?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Могу ли я не используя бд, обратиться к такому объекту на карте как здание (я предполагаю что здания на Яндекс картах составляют отдельный слой, и к каждому из них можно обратиться, так как у каждого здания есть такой атрибут как адрес).
Как обратиться через js к зданию?
Как изменить его цвет?

Answer (score 0):

Настроить подложку карты нельзя. Вы можете либо загрузить свой макет для всей карты (где дома будут отображаться другим цветом, например) https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_map

либо нанести на дома цветные прямоугольники 
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/rectangle